# Efficient ways to do a bulk partial update on a google cloud datastore entries using spring data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-data, google-cloud-datastore

I have a kind in google datastore with tens thousands of entries. I am using spring data to connect to and work on the datastore. I am trying to update one entity on a few (hundreds) rows on datastore.

The method I am trying to use does multiple gets with pagination and update the required attribute and saves all entries using dataStoreRepo.saveAll(list) and repeat until there are rows available for the query criteria.
Something like :

```
void partialUpdateSomething () { 
    List<Trains> trains = repo.findBySourceAndIsRunning("cityCode", false, Pageable.ofSize(50)); 
    while (!trains.isEmpty()) { 
        for(Train t:trains) { 
            train.isRunning(true); // updating isRunning to true 
        } 
        repo.saveAll(trains); // saving all the updated train objects 
        trains = repo.findBySourceAndIsRunning("cityCode", false, Pageable.ofSize(50)); 
    } 
}
```

Is there a better way to update just one or more entities ?

Comment: This looks the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524992/spring-gcp-datastore-performance-batch-processing-iteration-through-all-enti .  It looks like you should use the method that returns a Slice, and pass slice.nextPageable to subsequent calls findBySourceAndIsRunning.

Comment: @JimMorrison, Thanks for the response, but I cannot use slice for my scenario as I am updating one of the attributes that I am fetching with (isRunning in the example). If I use slice I'll skip a page for every iteration, that is why I am getting just the first page for each iteration.

Comment: The slice example in the other question uses cursors instead of offsets, so you won't skip a page by altering entities.  Instead the next query will start exactly where the previous query results ended.